# JQuery mobile - ChangePage results in white screen with "Undefined"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been having an issue for a few days now where the changePage function results in a white page with undefined in the top right corner. I originally was having an issue where parentheses in my URL was causing JQuery to break - I have found an [issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1383) related to this and the accepted [solution](https://github.com/michaelhull/jquery-mobile/commit/0ecd1c71422f014a1ef1335763336251ebf6684f). Currently my changePage function looks like this (Please note it worked up to alpha 3 release before the URL issue):

```
$.mobile.changePage("xd02main.do",
                             {type: "get",
                              data: dataString});
```

The results I am getting is that it does the change page successfully (results page shows) and then immediately shifts to the white undefined page (Not sure why!). Unfortunately I can't show screen shots as I am new here :(. Any suggestions would be great! If anyone has any more questions please let me know, I can give you more information if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is of some assistance?

http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

> options
>
> > Type: Object
> >
> > Properties:
> >
> > > **allowSamePageTransition** (default: false)
> > >
> > > Type: Boolean
> > >
> > > By default, changePage() ignores requests to change to the current active page.  Setting this option to true, allows the
> > >       request to execute. Developers should note that some of the page
> > >       transitions assume that the fromPage and toPage of a changePage
> > >       request are different, so they may not animate as expected. Developers
> > >       are responsible for either providing a proper transition, or turning
> > >       it off for this specific case.

If this doesn't solve your problem. Maybe you have somekind of script fireing in the second page when it is loaded?